# HTML5: Is file change notification in the API?

Tags: java, html, file-io, nio2

I took a look at the [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/).  I also looked at [this tutorial for handling files using HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Is there an API for file change notifications? I was hoping for something similar to [the WatchService API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) in the Java NIO2 library.

Comment: @Pekka, doesn't asking about HTML5 imply local files?

Comment: Local.  On the server, I could just use Java NIO2, Apache Commons, or something similar to monitor the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for file change notifications.